# Is there a way to standardize the business datatypes across all systems in organization?

Tags: python, data-access-layer

Can we do a  loosely coupled data access layer design in python?

Lets say,in a scenario i have an oracle table with column name ACTIVITY_ID with column datatype as Number(10). If this column is a foreign key in lot many tables,to hold the data of this column, can i create something like ACTID class (like a java object) and can be used across the code if i want to manipulate/hold the ACTIVITY_ID column data so that i could maintain consistency of business object columns. Is there any such possibility in python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try Django

As I understand it, Python does not natively have any database functionality. There are many different libraries/frameworks/etc. that can be used to provide database functionality to Python. I recommend taking a look at [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). With Django, you create a class for each database table and Django hides a **LOT** of the details, including allowing using with multiple database engines such as MySQL and PostgreSQL. Django handles Foreign Key relationships very well. Every table normally has a primary key, by default an auto-incremented `id` field. If you add a field like `activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)` then you now have a foreign key field `activity_id` in one table referencing the primary key field `id` in the Activity table. The Admin page will take care of cascading deletion of records if you delete an Activity record, and in general things "just work" the way you might expect them to.